# Can jQuery's .animate() method be made to affect variables, rather than CSS properties?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I started writing some JS code to cause a variables value to increase over time, up to a target value, with some form of 'ease-in'.

I realised that jquery already does this in it's .animate() method.  Of course, the method is for manipulating CSS properties, not general variables.

My question is, is there anything that can be done to hack it so that the method affects a variable, rather than a CSS property?

Comment: Can't you achieve the same effect fairly easily using `setTimeout()` directly?

Comment: Animate a variable with easeIn??? That makes no sense.

Comment: Can you use a CSS property as your variable? In other words, don't initialize an ordinary javascript variable. Instead, make a non-displaying div or such, and where your code needs to access the variable, have it access the css property of the div instead.

Comment: @JohnPick - yes, I was thinking about that, but it seems a little hacky.

Comment: @elclanrs - I never said 'animate a variable'.  I'm talking about having the animate() method manipulate a variable over time, rather than a css property (which is just another number).

Comment: @nnnnnn, /elclanrs - yes I could, I started down that direction, but would like to re-use the jquery logic if possible.

Comment: `animate()` is only meant for css properties, as you said. I suggest as others said that you do it with `setInverval/setTimeout`.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Yes, you can animate variables. [Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/KbqKQ/2/)

```
$({ n: 0 }).animate({ n: 10}, {
    duration: 1000,
    step: function(now, fx) {
        $("div").append(now + "<br />");
    }
});
```

In this example, I am animating *n* from 0 to 10 in 1 second. The `step` function is called during animation and from there you can retrieve the current value in `now`.

Personally, I used this technique to animate several css properties simultaneously in a non linear fashion.

Animate runs by modifying the value of properties declared in JS objects. Although `animate` is designed to change CSS scalar values, it can also safely be used for any generic property, as long `value` is a scalar one.
In fact, you can think of CSS as a set of JS objects, where properties are for example, `top`, `margin` etc.

Note that the following scripts do the same. They change CSS `left` from 0 to 10

```
$("#test").css('left', 0).animate({ left: 10 }, 1000);
```

is the same as

```
$({ left: 0 }).animate({ left: 10 }, {duration: 1000, step: function(now, fx) {
  $("#test").css('left', now);
}});
```

or, without using the `now` parameter

```
var obj = { left: 0 };
$(obj).animate({ left: 10 }, {duration: 1000, step: function() {
      $("#test").css('left', obj.left);
}});
```

To see them in action [click here](http://jsfiddle.net/AgPmN/)

Comment: Watch out for properties named like certain CSS attributes, such as `zoom`, `padding`, etc. jQuery tries to manipulate such properties as CSS, which obviously fails on a non-DOM object. A simple workaround is to prepend special names with a "_", so you'd animate `_zoom` instead of `zoom`.

Comment: @81403 That's not true. If you run `.animate` on a non-DOM object, jQuery only sees that object and will not apply any CSS to it. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/29Lobqg3/) I am animating a JS object with a `top` property and you can see that it doesn't move down.

Comment: @JoseRuiSantos How would you expect a javascript object to move down? :) Anyway, I didn't say all CSS attributes, just _some_. While `top` is working, `zoom` isn't, this should illustrate what I mean more clearly: http://jsfiddle.net/Le44kax5/

Comment: @81403 My bad. Yes, you are right. Thanks for pointing out this issue.