# Animating a single value within a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, animation, kineticjs

I'm trying to animate a shape i've created in HTML5.

```
myShape.drawFunc = function(){
    var context = this.getContext();
    context.beginPath();
    context.arc(480, 480, animationValue, startingPoint * Math.PI, endingPoint * Math.PI, false);
    context.lineTo(480,480);
    context.closePath();
    this.fillStroke();
}
```

I want to use jQuery.animate to change the `animationValue` from one value to another overtime. I'm not really sure how to achieve this, also I will need to run a function on every step of the animation `Layer.draw();` because my shape is a canvas shape.

Anyone know how to animate the `animationValue` in myShape.drawFunc ?

I should add that I'm trying to animate within a `myShape.on("mouseover",{});` does this pose any problem using the setInterval method etc?

UPDATE:

```
segment.on("mouseover",function(){
    var startingPoint = segData[index].startingPoint;
    var endingPoint = segData[index].endingPoint;
    var startingRadias = segData[index].radias;
    var maxRadias = 250;
    var updateRadias = startingRadias;

    setInterval(function(){
        if(updateRadias < maxRadias){
            updateRadias++;
            console.log("frame : "+updateRadias);
            this.drawFunc = function(){
                var context = this.getContext();
                context.beginPath();
                context.arc(480, 480, updateRadias, startingPoint * Math.PI, endingPoint * Math.PI, false);
                context.lineTo(480,480);
                context.closePath();
                this.fillStroke();
            }
            rawLayer.draw();
        }
    },1000/30);

});
```

the console.log is showing the they setInterval is being called but the shape doesn't seem to be redraw.

Comment: I don't think you'll be able to use jQuery.animate for this (unless you bind the value to some attribute of a dummy-DOM-Object). Why don't you just use a plain interval? Btw, this: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/canvas/notearsgame/ is a good tutorial on matters like this.

Comment: @m90 well I was looking into interval, obviously I can run my layer.draw(); easily with that, but can I fire a callback function with that method? That link is brilliant!!

Comment: @m90 It is possible to use `jQuery.animate()`. Check my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use `animate()` to change your `animationValue` from one value to another overtime:

```
var drawFunc = function (animationValue) {
    var context = $("#myCanvas")[0].getContext("2d");
    context.fillStyle="#FF0000";
    context.fillRect(animationValue, animationValue, 150, 75);
}, 
    from = 0, to = 50;

// now animate using the jQuery.animate()
$({ n: from }).animate({ n: to}, {
    duration: 1000,
    step: function(now, fx) {
        drawFunc(now);
    }
});
```

In this case, we are animating from 0 to 50 in 1 second.

This is not exactly your animation code, but you should get the hang of it. **[Demo Here](http://jsfiddle.net/HtcS9/)**

More information on [animating variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9324081/can-jquerys-animate-method-be-made-to-affect-variables-rather-than-css-prop/9324325#9324325)

Comment: Just saw this, I didn't know about that at all, that's a pretty handy tool.

Comment: pretty handy for using easing functions for non-DOM purposes.

Answer (score 2):

```
var FPS = 30;
setInterval(function() {
  update();
  draw();
}, 1000/FPS);
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.setInterval