# Can't animate the border color with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, animation, html-table

I have this table:

```
<table id="social" border="5">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fyannbane.blogspot.com%2F&amp;send=false&amp;layout=button_count&amp;width=100&amp;show_faces=true&amp;action=like&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;font&amp;height=21&amp;appId=177127339057410" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:100px; height:21px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
        </td>

        <td>
            <a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-url="http://yannbane.blogspot.com/" data-via="Yannbane">Tweet</a>
        </td>

        <td>
            <g:plusone></g:plusone>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

And I'd like to animate its borders with jquery, like this:

```
$("#social").animate({"borderTopColor": "#f00", "borderBottomColor": "#fff"}, 800);
```

But, it doesn't work! Nothing happens at all, even no errors are shown...

I've also tried this:

```
$("#social").animate({"border-top-tolor": "#f00", "border-bottom-color": "#fff"}, 800);
```

But with same results... How do you do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery animate border color on hover?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/813493/jquery-animate-border-color-on-hover)

Comment: @epascarello There's no indication the OP is using the Color plugin

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [jQuery animate reference](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) (my emphasis)

> All animated properties should be animated to a single numeric value,
>   except as noted below; **most properties that are non-numeric cannot
>   be animated using basic jQuery functionality (For example, width,
>   height, or left can be animated but background-color cannot be,**
>   unless the jQuery.Color() plugin is used). Property values are treated
>   as a number of pixels unless otherwise specified. The units em and %
>   can be specified where applicable.

In short, it looks like you either need the [Color()](http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/color) plugin or you need to roll your own.

Andrew's answer on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2302005/156755) seems to do what you need for very little work.

Answer (score 3):

You should definitely use the Color plugin as others already pointed out.

However, as a side note, you can use instead an interesting technique that consists animating variables (in this case `color` variable) and then do your stuff in the `step` function.

This might be a bit overkill, but gives you lots of flexibility to do custom animations:

```
// animate color variable from 0x0 to 0xF
$({ color: 0 }).animate({ color: 15}, {
    duration: 800,
    step: function(now, fx) {
        var hexValue = Math.round(now).toString(16);
        $("#social").css({
            'border-top-color': '#' + hexValue + '00',
            'border-bottom-color': '#' + hexValue + hexValue + hexValue
        });
    }
});
```

**[jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ruisoftware/7zYFA/2/)**

Here is [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9324325/607874) regarding this tecnhique.

Comment: +1 While this might not be the cleanest solution, it's an interesting and powerful twist - and one I'm likely to take advantage of for future projects - Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @Basic You are welcome! This is what I love about SO, that we can help and learn from each other.