# jquery "animate" variable value

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, jquery-animate

I need to "animate" a variable with jquery.

**Example:**
The variable value is 1. The value should be 10 after 5 seconds.
It should be increase "smoothly".

Hope that you know what I mean.

Thank you!

Comment: do you want to keep on incrementing this variable after fixed time??

Comment: It should be increase "smoothly". I forgot to say it...

Comment: You have an elegant solution here http://stackoverflow.com/a/9324325/607874

Answer (score 13, accepted):

What you require is the step parameter in the [`$().animate`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) function.

```
var a = 1;
jQuery('#dummy').animate({ /* animate dummy value */},{
    duration: 5000, 
    step: function(now,fx){ 
        a = 1 + ((now/100)*9); 
    }
});
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wmhVc/)

Comment: The solution is ok. The problem is it's very slow.

Comment: @Ties +1 It works, but you really don't need to bind the animation to a dummy HTML element. See my answer in http://stackoverflow.com/a/9324325/607874

Comment: @JoseRuiSantos i know, the answer Sudhir gave is probably the best answer.

Answer (score 25):

try:

```
$({someValue: 0}).animate({someValue: 10}, {
    duration: 5000,
    step: function() { 
        $('#el').text(Math.ceil(this.someValue));
    }
});

<div id="el"></div>
```

Comment: nice i didn't know you could do it this way, i knew about the step function (as you can see in my answer) but this is good stuff! remove the `Math.ceil` and you're golden :)

Comment: @Ties Math.ceil is used in this case so that its rounded up to upper value, else you'd be getting 9.99858544, etc

Comment: yeah but you lose the smoothness, you can add a `complete` parameter to finish it

Answer (score 11):

[image: representation]

```
var snail = {speed:0};
$(snail).animate({speed: 10}, 5000);
```

[demo](http://jsbin.com/gewak/3)

Answer (score 2):

This should work for you:

```
var a = 1;
var b = setInterval(function() {
  console.log(a);
  a++;
  if (a == 10) { clearInterval(b); }
}, 500);
```

Comment: jup made a similar [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Fbhs9/2/) note that the timing won't be 100% accurate but that might be not a big problem depending on the case :)

Answer (score 0):

Use setInterval :

```
percentage = 0;
startValue = 1;
finishValue = 5;
currentValue = 1;
interval = setInterval(function(){ 
   percentage ++; 
   currentValue = startValue + ((finishValue - startValue) * percentage) / 100;
   doSomething(currentValue);
   if (percentage == 100) clearInterval(interval);
 }, duration / 100)

function doSomething(val) { /*process value*/}
```

Answer (score 0):

Html mark up as
**Html**

```
<span id="changeNumber">1</span>
```

You can change its value after 5 seconds.
**JQuery:**

```
setInterval(function() {        
        $('#changeNumber').text('10');
    },5000);
```

Here is a Demo http://jsfiddle.net/Simplybj/Fbhs9/

Comment: in this example you can better use `setTimeout`. You set it to 10 every 5 seconds now... (while it already is 10)

Answer (score 0):

As addition to Ties answer - you dont event need to append dummy element to the DOM. I do it like this:

```
$.fn.animateValueTo = function (value) {

    var that = this;

    $('<span>')
        .css('display', 'none')
        .css('letter-spacing', parseInt(that.text()))
        .animate({ letterSpacing: value }, {
            duration: 1000,
            step: function (i) {
                that.text(parseInt(i));
            }
        });

    return this;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var varToAnimate = 1;
$(window).animate({
    varToAnimate: 10
}, 5000);
```

**Note: This only works if the variable was set with `var varToAnimate` or `window.varToAnimate`.**

When you set a variable, it creates a property in the window object. `jQuery.animate()` animates properties, so `$(window)` gets the window object, and `varToAnimate: 10` animates the window's varToAnimate property to 10.

Answer (score -1):

```
​var blub = 1;
setTimeout(function () {
    blub = 10;
}, 5000);
```

Comment: Ahahahhahahahhahahahha, that is so funny! +1

Answer (score -1):

increment with `setTimeout`

```
x = 1

for(i=0;i<1000;i+=100){
  setTimeout(function(){
    console.log(x++)
  },i)
}
```