# Animate multiple variable values in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, jquery-animate

Can I possibly animate multiple variable values in a single animation? I would like to animate two variable values from this value to that value.

In this code, I would want the x and y values to animate from a given value to another value but I can only do it with the x. (Code was based from an answer here but would like some help in doing so with multiple values: [jquery "animate" variable value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12317523/jquery-animate-variable-value))

```
$({someValue: 0}).animate({someValue: -2147.141601481341}, {
    duration: 5000,
    step: function() { 
        mainMap.pan({x: someValue, y: -5937.031428375433})
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add multiple properties to your Object. Try it:

```js
//initial values          end values
$({x: 0, y: 10}).animate({x: 10, y: 0}, {
    duration: 5000,
    step: function() { 
        $('#x').text(Math.round(this.x));
        $('#y').text(Math.round(this.y));
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

x: <span id="x"></span> <br/>
y: <span id="y"></span>
```

Your code should look something like:

```
$({x: 0, y: 0}).animate({x: -2147.141601481341, y: -5937.031428375433}, {
    duration: 5000,
    step: function() { 
        mainMap.pan(this)
        // or mainMap.pan({x: this.x, y: this.y, foo: "bar"})
    }
});
```

Comment: Oh my God thank you it worked. Thank you so much. Thank you.