# Assigning Object in function to Variable or call setState w/o this?

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I'm sure this is rather simple, but with me being new to JS and React I can't seem to find an answer to this.

Basically, I have a function that uses the JQ animate method to act as a counter of sorts.  The function looks like this:

```
$({countNum: 99}).animate({countNum: 1000}, {
     duration: 2000,
     easing:'linear',
     step: function() {
      var counter = Math.floor(this.countNum)
      console.log(counter)
     },
     complete: function() {
       return 'counter done';
     }
 });
```

I am trying to setState within the `step` so that I can simulate a counter on my app as it counts up to a specific number.  In order to set the state I need to bind `this` to the object in the animate function, however then I can't figure out how to access the `countNum` so that it increases.

Any ideas? Or am I approaching this totally wrong.

Comment: `$({countNum: 99})` is totally wrong. Read the jQuery API again please.

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-context-inside-a-callback) should give you some good insights.  May even be a duplicate, if you tidy yours up a bit to make it a bit clearer.

Comment: To access `countNum` in the `step` callback, you can use [one of these techniques](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9324325/607874)

Comment: @PraveenKumar No, it's not wrong. You can use `animate` to animate object properties. You might want to check the link from my previous comment.

Comment: @JoseRuiSantos Thanks. Learnt something new.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign "this" to a specific variable before entering in your callback

```
var _mythis = this;
```

and then use "_mythis" to call member function/variable

```
_mythis.myJQfct();
```

But I'm not sure it's what you need to do in your case.

Comment: I knew this and I didn't even think to try it.  Thanks for the reminder :).  Got it working.